# How to Change Typesetting Engine in LEd (Latex Editor)

Tags: xetex, led-editor

How to Change Typesetting Engine in LEd (Latex Editor). I'm trying to build a simple latex document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Elephant}

\begin{document}
My Name is Atinesh
\end{document}
```

I'm getting this error message

[image]

I understand message is saying to chnage the Typesetting engine to  XeTeX or LuaTeX. But I couldn't be able to find any option to change the typesetting Engine in  "LEd 0.53". Can anybody tell me where that option is located.

Comment: The LEd program has been unmaintained for several years.

Comment: @egreg Then which Texteditor I should use

Comment: Go to this `big list` maintained on this site http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides.  You can read and compare.  Then pick one.  Personally I use Texmaker most of the time.  I use Texworks from Miktex for certain debugging.  Also, I use TexStudio for selected features and RStudio for integrating R and Latex.    My primary requirements are 1) currently being maintained with available help forums  2) Prefer an IDE that has implementations on Windows, MacOS, and Linux.   But honestly, the choice of IDE is very personal and needs to match your workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LEd program is no longer maintained for several years, I switched to Texmaker.